# How to see entire longtext column in MySQL client

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to view the entire text of a LONGTEXT column when we select it using the MySQL command line client - mysql?

This query:

```
select query from statement_analysis;
```

only shows 64 characters of the query.

This is on 5.7.25.

example from 5.7.33:

```
--------------
select max(length(query))
from statement_analysis
--------------

+--------------------+
| max(length(query)) |
+--------------------+
|                 65 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

--------------
select query
from statement_analysis
where
length(query) > 60
--------------

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| query                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT `DIGEST` , `CURRENT_SCH ... . `events_statements_history`  |
| SELECT COALESCE ( SCHEMA_NAME  ... ) - INTERVAL ? SQL_TSI_SECOND  |
| SELECT `sys` . `format_stateme ... cy` , `sys` . `format_time` (  |
| SELECT `performance_schema` .  ... IMER_WAIT` AS `avg_latency` ,  |
| SELECT COALESCE ( SCHEMA_NAME  ... statements_summary_by_digest`  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you run this command with 1000 or more it expands this to 1000:

```
set @sys.statement_truncate_len = 1000
```

But I would like to get the full query. It looks like the general log has the full length queries for what that is worth.

Bobby

Comment: Might be here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-format-statement.html

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150259/how-to-retrieve-truncated-queries-from-sys-statements-with-temp-tables-view

Comment: Please provide a minimal test case showing that it chops off at 64.

Comment: Done. You can tell they are chopped off because they have ... in them.

Answer (score 0):

The query column on x$statement_analysis shows more than 1000 characters. This was big enough for the problem I was working on. I do not know if it has some limit.

Here is the max size on the production database that I was working on:

```
--------------
select max(length(query))
from x$statement_analysis
--------------

+--------------------+
| max(length(query)) |
+--------------------+
|               1747 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

So the answer is to use sys.x$statement_analysis instead of sys.statement_analysis and your query text will not be as limited.

Bobby